# Migration from ASP.NET MVC2 Priview 2 to MVC2 RC: Any breaking changes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to migrate from ASP.NET MVC2 Priview 2 to MVC2 RC, because new version of Telerik is enforcing it.

I had big problems while migrating from MVC 1.0 to MVC 2.0 Preview 2, so I wanted to confirm with you guys before continuing.

Has anyone migrated from Prev2 to RC? Was there any problems? Are they easy to solve?
Any suggestions are greatly welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Changes in ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM

No new breaking changes were introduced by the ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM release.

### Changes in ASP.NET MVC 2 Release Candidate 2

Every property for model objects that use `IDataErrorInfo` to perform validation is validated, regardless of whether a new value was set. In ASP.NET MVC 1.0, only properties that had new values set would be validated. In ASP.NET MVC 2, the Error property of `IDataErrorInfo` is called only if all the property validators were successful.

### Changes in ASP.NET MVC 2 Release Candidate 1

**IIS script mapping script is no longer available in the installer**
The IIS script mapping script is a command-line script that is used to configure script maps for IIS 6 and for IIS 7 in Classic mode. The script-mapping script is not needed if you use the Visual Studio Development Server or if you use IIS 7 in Integrated mode. The scripts are available as a separate unsupported download on the ASP.NET CodePlex site.

**The Html.Substitute helper method in MVC Futures is no longer available**
Due to changes in the rendering behavior of MVC view engines, the `Html.Substitute` helper method does not work and has been removed.

(See the Release Notes [**here**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C9BA1FE1-3BA8-439A-9E21-DEF90A8615A9&displaylang=en) for more information)